# How to remove complete data in installation path while uninstalling windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I had successfully created Setup file(.exe) using windows forms application in C#.
Setup is installed and my functionality using app is working fine.
Installation path is in `C-Drive : **C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\MyApp**`

To install latest Setup with updated code, i uninstalled existing application from control panel .After Uninstalled the app, installed folder is showing deleted.

After that , I installed latest Setup without changing Installation path.
same path again :`**C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\MyApp**`

Here i got problems, **data relates to old set Up not removed completely.**

I used Sq-lite Database as local DB in windows application, Latest installed Setup showing old data because of same installed path.
if installation path is changed, it is fine. but **i cannot say to my clients to change installation path every time.**

**How can we remove all files while Uninstalling ?**
Is there anything to do in my Setup ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the [`Installer.Uninstall`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.uninstall.aspx) method to remove your data properly.

Also you can configure it manually via [Setup & Deployment project](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4901ac0c-e189-44a5-a10c-911e9f3346d9/how-to-make-uninstall-in-setup-and-deploy-visual-studio-2008?forum=csharplanguage):

> In SetUp and Deployment:
>
> 1. After creating the setup project right click on your project add
>      -->Primary output. So, automatically all the related files of your project will get added to it.
> 2. Now, make a short cut of ur primary output rename to Uninstall the product , cut and paste in User's Programme menu-->TestFolder--->Uninstall the product.
> 3. Now, right click on the shortcut--->properties. On the right side you get few fields choose on among it named as arguments type the same `/u=[ProductCode]`
> 4. And hit F4 on ur setup and deployment project make sure that `DetectNewInstalledVersions` and `RemovePreviousVersions` these two fields to `true`.